# How can I import NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am very new to Python and I don't understand many of the other answers available on this topic (or namely, what the solutions are suggesting), so I would appreciate it if someone could explain in simple terms how to solve the error when I attempt to import NumPy, matplotlib, or other packages in PyCharm:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 "/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/Learning/Rosalind Learning/Early Practice.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/Learning/Rosalind Learning/Early Practice.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the computer does not recognize NumPy. This could be for multiple reasons:

1. You did not install NumPy. If that is the case these steps:
   On Debian/Ubuntu run:

   ```
   aptitude install python-numpy
   ```

   On Windows, download the installer from http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/
2. You may have incorrectly installed NumPy. You can uninstall it and try again with the steps above.

Comment: Looking at the traceback, the OP seems to be on an Apple OS-X machine.

Comment: Good first answer. Pro tip: make stuff less bold. It looks like you're shouting, and people won't like it

Comment: You aren't going to edit it? I'd remove my upvote if I could.