# Can't import numpy into python after multiple resets/reinstalls

Tags: python, numpy

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893602/how-to-install-numpy-for-python-3-6), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321473/how-can-i-import-numpy?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906575/how-to-import-numpy-in-the-python-shell) I am still unable to import numpy into python, either inside a shell or directly in PyCharm.

I have uploaded a screenshot for context and am willing to upload any other results that might help resolve this issue.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: How many Python installations do you have now on your system? Are you sure the one you are running is the same pip is pointed to?

Comment: @jaboja It is definitely possible that I have 2 or 3 installations; is there an easy way to check which one pip is pointed to, or should I try to find and delete all of them then reinstall?

Comment: @jaboja I found a total of four copies of python; how can I tell which one pip is pointed at?

Comment: `where.exe` command may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

This will make sure you install numpy for the same python version which is invoked when you call `python` on the terminal.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Any chance there's a simple solution like this for working inside pycharm?  It still can't find numpy in there.

Comment: PyCharm lets you choose the python interpreter you want to use for the project. Just install numpy for the interpreter configured for your project. OR you could also try working with a virtualenv

Comment: I'm very new to programming and picking up a project that a friend left off; is there any way to tell which python interpreter is configured for the project?

Comment: In the pycharm sidebar, you should see a tiny arrow next to "external dependencies", clicking there should show you the location of the python interpreter your project is using.

Comment: Here is a picture of what I see there http://tinypic.com/r/zloffq/9, I'm not quite sure how to parse it. Is there some way to point the command prompt at this python installation and put numpy in there?

Comment: Your python interpreter is present in `C:\Users\alecj\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe`. It appears to me that you are already using a virtualenv. See this page for instructions on how to install a package using PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#install_package

Comment: Thank you, I'll look over there and try to figure it out.